# Проблема при запуске команды в скрипте: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

Необходимо написать скрипт на python для Linux, одна из задач скрипта это распаковать запароленные архивы в папку, для дальнейшей работы с этими файлами( python взял в руки только сейчас) 
Вот скрипт:

```
from subprocess import call
call( "unzip -P infected 'arch0.zip' -d all/" )
```

Скрипт лежит в папке с архивами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но при запуске возникают ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Clam.py", line 6, in
>   
>       z.extractall()    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1040, in extractall
>       self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1028, in extract
>       return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1082, in _extract_member
>       with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 990, in open
>       "password required for extraction" % name RuntimeError: File  is encrypted, password
>   required for extraction

Ответ

```
import zipfile

zipcheck = zipfile.is_zipfile('./test.zip')
if zipcheck == True:
    z = zipfile.ZipFile('./test.zip', 'r')
    z.extractall( pathToDir, pwd = 'password' ) 
    z.close()
else:
    print('Not valid ZIP')
```

Comment: А у вас unzip в системе-то есть?

Comment: сообщение об ошибке стоит как текст включить, чтобы помочь людям с похожей проблемой найти вопрос.

Comment: Окей, переделаю

Comment: как заставить subprocess.call работать  — это один вопрос. Как с помощью zipfile модуля запароленный архив распаковать — это другой. Я понимаю, что для вас это одна и та же задача, а разрешив проблему с распаковкой в вашей программе могут и другие ошибки быть. Лучше ограничиться одной проблемой на вопрос (чтобы большему кругу людей помочь). По необходимости можно несколько отдельных Stack Overflow вопросов задать.

Comment: не помещайте свой ответ в вопрос. Опубликуйте ответ как ответ вместо этого -- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import zipfile


zipcheck = zipfile.is_zipfile('test.zip')
if zipcheck == True:
    z = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'r')
    z.extractall() 
    z.close()
else:
    print('Not valid ZIP')
```

Comment: не, не помогло
поменял имя файла с test.zip на arch0.zip, но не сработало

Comment: Что не сработало? какая ошибка?

Comment: если вы в Питоне хотите распаковать архив: `shutil.unpack_archive()`

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: сейчас в текст задачи ответ закину

Comment: не используйте конструкций типа: `if condition == True`. Пишите просто `if condition:` К примеру: `if zipfile.is_zipfile('test.zip'): ...`.  Вместо проверки (которая не 100%), можно сразу в ZipFile путь передать (исключение выкинет, если нет архива, неверный архив итд). Ошибки всё равно придётся обрабатывать¶  Используйте `with`-конструкцию, чтобы закрыть архив даже если исключение при распаковке возникнет (пример в моём ответе можно увидеть).

Answer (score 0):

Функции в `subprocess` модуле ожидают [команду как список, а не строку по умолчанию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(['echo', 'first arg', 'second'])
```

Вашу команду можно в список превратить используя [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split("unzip -P infected 'arch0.zip' -d all/")
['unzip', '-P', 'infected', 'arch0.zip', '-d', 'all/']
```

То есть запуск `unzip` команды должен выглядеть как:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(['unzip', '-P', 'infected', 'arch0.zip', '-d', 'all/'])
```

Если хочется в Питоне распаковать zip-архив с паролем в `all` папку:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('arch0.zip') as archive:
    archive.extractall('all', pwd='infected')
```